# new OnClickListener() vs new View.OnClickListener()

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclicklistener

When I want to add an argument to setOnClickListener for such as a button, I click on View.OnClickListener() from eclipse alarm, but eclipse types **new OnClickListener()** instead of **new View.OnClickListener()**. What is difference between these codes?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() ...)
```

and

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ...)
```

Comment: Captial letters were modified!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse automatically imports `View.OnClickListener` so you don't have to use the `View.` prefix.

If you `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;` you can just use `OnClickListener`

**but**

if you `import android.view.View;` you have to use `View.OnClickListener`

Check how your imports list changes and it'll make more sense.

Comment: OK. Thanks. It was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

If your class extends from View class or you imported View class before, there is no need to use "View" at the front.

If you did not import View class you need to write View.

Answer (score 0):

There is no diffrence mate.

It will also know that the onClickListener is pointed to a View.
But If you want to see it better in your code that its a part of a View than write it down like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using only `View.OnClickListener` in your class, then it's just a matter of preference and additional information.

But consider you're writing a complex activity also using `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`. Then you have to use the full definition with outer and inner class for at least one of these.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method `setonclicklistener`. It is `setOnClickListener`.
Similarly it is `OnClickListener` not `onclicklistener`.

And, You can use

1. `button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()...);`

and

2. `button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()...);`

But for using 2nd  way you must have below `import` in your file.

```
import  android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

But I'd suggest using `View.OnClickListener()` because `OnClickListener()` is the method associated with `View` class also and `DialogInterface` class too. So if you are using `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` later in your code in the future, then you have to change that back to `View.OnClickListener()` and `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`